# Can I integrate Log Analytics with log4j2?

Tags: log4j2, slf4j, azure-databricks, azure-log-analytics, veracode

**Use-case:** Running Spark job in Databricks and monitoring logs in LogAnalytics.

**Issue:** In *Veracode* report, I am getting security vulnerabilities(*CRLF*) with *Slf4j* logger.

I am looking for other approaches, with *Log4j2* I don't see any issues.

Now my question is, I want to integrate ***LogAnalytics with Log4j2***, is that possible in my case?

Comment: We are working to locate the relevant owners of the libraries, but for faster response  would request you to log a question/issue to the library repo - https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring